# ContentDisposition class to build file content disposition

Tags: go

The `C#` has `ContentDispositionHeaderValue` class to build non unicode and unicode file content dispositions. Does Go has something similar?

This is example from c#

```
void Main()
{
    var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    contentDisposition.FileName = "与自.pdf";
    contentDisposition.FileNameStar = "与自.pdf";     
    contentDisposition.ToString().Dump();
}
```

and the result is

```
attachment; filename="=?utf-8?B?5LiO6IeqLnBkZg==?="; filename*=utf-8''%E4%B8%8E%E8%87%AA.pdf
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#BEncoding

Comment: @Peter that link explain how to parse content disposition but I am looking how to build it.

Comment: That package does both encoding and deciding. See the example for [WordEncoder.Encode](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#WordEncoder.Encode).